# Structure of XML File - Capturing Vertice Data with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have the following xml file which I am parsing using NSXMLParser :

```
<geometry id="window_strip-mesh" name="window_strip">
  <mesh>
    <source id="window_strip-mesh-positions">
      <float_array id="window_strip-mesh-positions-array" count="1302">399.297 -87842.3 233.334 399.297 -89320.4 233.334 -821.159 
...
</float_array>
```

My question is how can I detect / capture the values that are listed after the > (i.e the 399.297 -87842.3 and so on). Is NSXML Parser able to pick these up ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement the NSXMLDelegate methods,

```
-  (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;

-  (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock;
```

and

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

For your example you have to put the following line in the `didStartElement:` Method:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"float_array"]) { 
    float_array_bool = YES;
}
```

Then in the  `-  (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;` Method you can implement

```
if (float_array_bool) {
    [yourItemToStoreValues.floatArray addObject:string];
}
```

In the `parserDidEndElement:` Method you have to unset tho bool value:

```
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"float_array"]) {
        float_array_bool    = NO;
    }
```

That should do the trick